# mongoid where on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

Since mongo isn't relational I'm wondering how to find a particular type on a has_many polymorphic association.

I have 3 models, [Place, City, & Country] all 3 can have reviews (polymorphic)

How can I return all reviews with a particular model association?  I know how to do it on a simple has_many association but not on a polymorphic one?

Normally I would do something like this:

```
  @user = User.where(username: params[:user]).first
  @user ? @reviews = @reviews.where(user_id: @user.id) : @reviews = nil
```

But for a polymorphic association I'm lost?

```
#@reviews = params[:review_type].constantize if params[:review_type].present? #@reviews.reviewable.where(review_type: params[:review_type])

@reviews = Review.order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page])#.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Comment: Why not to use `@user.reviews`?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear, it's not the user model, I was just using that as an example of how I would normally do it (non polymorphically)

Comment: I understand, but polymorphic associations work similar. So you can use `Place.first.reviews` or `City.first.reviews`

Comment: Yes, but like the first example I want to search thru all reviews not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed your polymorphic relationship was named `reviewable` You can query your reviews by their association type like this:

```
Review.where(:reviewable_type => "Place") # Returns all reviews for 'places'
Review.where(:reviewable_type => "City") # Returns all reviews for 'cities'
Review.where(:reviewable_type => "Country") # Returns all reviews for 'countries'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you well define your associations association in your model your just need call the method.